# Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.pdf denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, file-permissions

I have been dealing with an issue regarding my ELB deployment to our new test environment with a load balancer. 
I previously ran the code through testing, and through RDP connection to the instance, I was able to save a PDF file I created with iTextSharp under a folder I created with my code.

However, once I created the multi-instance environment and wanted to go forward with an ELB deployment, I ran into an access issue.

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(fileName, fileMode.OpenOrCreate));
```

Here, I use `Server.MapPath` to generate the `fileName` variable and try to get the `FileStream` on the same path. The sample path I arrive at is the one mentioned in the title: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\folder\file.pdf`

To make sure of things, I created a `folder` folder under my project, put a txt file under (`Text.txt`), published through ELB with this version, and I was able to access this file in my website's domain with the `/folder/Text.txt`

I have checked out security groups and role management sections in the AWS Console, but I couldn't find anything that resembled an I/O permission. Is there a possible workaround this issue? I searched around the Internet, but the only things I saw involved working through IIS, which isn't useful for me, since I won't be connecting to the instances via RDP in this case.

Edit: Exception e-mail information I receive.

```
Exception Details:
Message :   Access to the path 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\agreements\TM_1efced9a40fc46d2b2da2ebd97847de1.pdf' is 
denied. 

Source :    mscorlib 
Stacktrace :    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String 
maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, 
FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 
bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String 
msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at 
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, 
Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode 
mode) at Cepstop.Web.Controllers.CommonController.ExportHtmlToPDF(String 
fileName, FibaModel fModel, String type) in 
C:\Projects\Cepstop\Cepstop.Web\Controllers\CommonController.cs:line 926 
Related Function Details:

Related Function Name :     WinIOError 

Parameters:
System.Int32 :      errorCode 
System.String :     maybeFullPath
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is an iText question?

Comment: Because there seems to be some fundamental differences in using FileStream or MemoryStream, so, I thought it might prove to be a clue leading to a way out.

Comment: Again, I am not sure how that relates to iText? I really don't want to sound pedantic. Try extracting the `FileStream` out of the `PdfWriter.GetInstance`. My gut feeling is that you will still have an error. However, you haven't posted a full stack trace, so I am stabbing in the dark. Please provide more information.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear regarding my question, no worries. I edited the question post to include the error details I receive.

Comment: Unfortunately, based on the Exception you posted, I can now confirm that your error is unrelated to iText. It's just default .NET file I/O. I will remove the `itext` tag and maybe add another more useful tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help and attention.